# Error when making dynamic lib from .o

Tags: macos, linker, dylib

I'm trying to make dynamic lib from set of .o files, but when i do

> gcc -dynamiclib -current_version 1.0  mymod.o -o mylib.dylib

or

> ld *.o -o mylib.dylib

i get a lot of errors like:

> "_objc_msgSend", referenced from:
>         -[NSObject(NSObject_SBJSON) JSONFragment] in NSObject+SBJSON.o
>
> "operator new(unsigned long)", referenced from:
>         MStatistic::instance()      in MStatistic.o
>         StatisticProfileLoggingObserver::instance()      in StatisticObserver.o
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Can you please help me, how to solve it and get my .dylib?

Comment: so, when loading this lib, i whenever get undefined symbols, it cures by passing link with framework command. for example gcc -dynamiclib -current_version 1.0 mymod.o -o mylib.dylib **-framework Foundation**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass `-undefined dynamic_lookup` as an option to `ld`, or:
`-Wl,-undefined -Wl,dynamic_lookup` to `gcc` or `clang` (which passes it to the linker).

Answer (score 0):

From this line:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

it sounds like you are building some libraries that have make files that only build for 32-bit architectures.

You need to modify the makefiles for *all* the libraries / frameworks you're building to build both 32-bit and 64-bit; and in a practical sense, all shipping MacOS machines are 64-bit capable so it may just be safe to build ***only*** for 64-bit.

In your compile / linking lines, add something like this:  "`-arch x86_64`" and that should compile things for the 64-bit side.  To do both 32 & 64-bit, you'll basically need to duplicate the compile & link lines with their own "`-arch i386`" and "`-arch x86_64`" lines.